# no results are being displayed in the view after a query is run

Tags: jsf, primefaces, derby

i have a search query that should search a database and return all the details that match that username or contain any part of the search string

```
 <h:form id="searchForm">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Search: "/>
                    <h:inputText id="search" value="#{userdetailsController.search}"  />   
                    &nbsp;
                    <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{userdetailsController.submit}" ajax="true" update="UserTableSearch"/>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <p:dataTable id="UserTableSearch"
                                 widgetVar="UserTableSearch" 
                                 paginator="true" rows="10"
                                 value="#{userdetailsController.item}"
                                 var="item"
                                 emptyMessage="No details was found with given criteria">

                        <p:column id="id"  
                                  headerText="i.d." 
                                  sortBy="id">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsTitle_id}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{userdetails.username}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="username"   
                                  headerText="username"
                                  sortBy="username">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsTitle_username}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{userdetails.username}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
```

that is the view, where the user can search the username, it should automatically then update the datatable with the search results, however currently is displaying the empty message of

```
emptyMessage="No details was found with given criteria"
```

how can i check to see if the data being passed to the view contains some values,

this is the userdetails controller it calls

```
@Named("userdetailsController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserdetailsController implements Serializable {

    private Userdetails current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB

    private Richard.beans.UserdetailsFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;
    private String search;

    private List<Userdetails> item; // No need for DataModel here.

    public List<Userdetails> getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String submit() {
        item = ejbFacade.searchByString(search);
        return ""; //change this !, testing only
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    public UserdetailsController() {
    }

    public Userdetails getSelected() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new Userdetails();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    private UserdetailsFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
        if (pagination == null) {
            pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {

                @Override
                public int getItemsCount() {
                    return getFacade().count();
                }

                @Override
                public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                    return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
                }
            };
        }
        return pagination;
    }

    public String prepareList() {
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String prepareView() {
        current = (Userdetails) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "View";
    }

    public String prepareCreate() {
        current = new Userdetails();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
        return "Create";
    }

    public String create() {
        try {
            getFacade().create(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("UserdetailsCreated"));
            return prepareCreate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String prepareEdit() {
        current = (Userdetails) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "Edit";
    }

    public String update() {
        try {
            getFacade().edit(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("UserdetailsUpdated"));
            return "View";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String destroy() {
        current = (Userdetails) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        performDestroy();
        recreatePagination();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String destroyAndView() {
        performDestroy();
        recreateModel();
        updateCurrentItem();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            return "View";
        } else {
            // all items were removed - go back to list
            recreateModel();
            return "List";
        }
    }

    private void performDestroy() {
        try {
            getFacade().remove(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("UserdetailsDeleted"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    private void updateCurrentItem() {
        int count = getFacade().count();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= count) {
            // selected index cannot be bigger than number of items:
            selectedItemIndex = count - 1;
            // go to previous page if last page disappeared:
            if (pagination.getPageFirstItem() >= count) {
                pagination.previousPage();
            }
        }
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            current = getFacade().findRange(new int[]{selectedItemIndex, selectedItemIndex + 1}).get(0);
        }
    }

    //datatable for all results
    public DataModel getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
        }
        return items;
    }

    private void recreateModel() {
        items = null;
    }

    private void recreatePagination() {
        pagination = null;
    }

    public String next() {
        getPagination().nextPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String previous() {
        getPagination().previousPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), false);
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), true);
    }

    public Userdetails getUserdetails(java.lang.Integer id) {
        return ejbFacade.find(id);
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = Userdetails.class)
    public static class UserdetailsControllerConverter implements Converter {

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            UserdetailsController controller = (UserdetailsController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "userdetailsController");
            return controller.getUserdetails(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof Userdetails) {
                Userdetails o = (Userdetails) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getId());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + Userdetails.class.getName());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `getItem()` method is called to populate the datable.  In that method you can iterate through the list or just print out the number of items.

Also in `submit()` check to see if there's any value in `search` or if it's being called at all. I suspect `search` is null.

Your inputtext is not a PrimeFaces component. I would change it to PrimeFaces. There's render time differences which may account for search string not being there.